# rails 3 heroku push master issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

when I push my rails 3 app git heroku master I get this error msg:

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
 !     Heroku Bamboo does not include any Rails gems by default.
 !     You'll need to declare it in either .gems or Gemfile.
 !     See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for details on specifying gems.
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Rails gem specified.

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:glowing-rain-62.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:glowing-rain-62.git'

I have gem 'rails', '3.0.3' specified in my gemfile, so I am not sure what the issue is....If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that Gemfile is case sensitive.  Make sure the file is actually IN your repo.  You should also have a Gemfile.lock file too.  Which version of bundler are you running?

Comment: im running bundler 1.0.7. When I made my commit I did see both my gemfile & gemlock file in the local repo & on github. I migrated over to bamboo-mri-1.9.2 because I am running ruby version 1.9.2. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully deployed to Heroku before?

If not you may want to double-check that rails, 3.0.3 is committed to your Git repo just as a sanity check...

Comment: I have deployed to Heroku before but with rails 2.3 & ruby version 1.8.7. Im not sure why it's not deploying to Heroku but im gonna try to figure it out. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be connected with the heroku server type (or idiomatically: stack). The normal stack (called Aspen, I think) is runned by Debian Etch which doesn't support newer versions of Rails (i.e. Rails 3) and neither Sinatra.

To solve the problem you can switch to the Bamboo stack which is runned by Debian Lenny. You can do it by switching the stack as followed:

```
heroku create yourname --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

"yourname" is of course the name of your application. After that it should work as it should.